# What's the probability that nine people were born in the same two months (but not the same month)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find the probability that nine people were born in the same two months (but not
all in the same month).

No clue how to approach this. I was thinking well you have to choose 8 out of the 9 people and then match them up to one month. Then take the remaining person and match him up to another month. How do i do that?

Comment: Your suggested approach will not work.

Comment: really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Imagine that you pick your $9$ people and arrange them in alphabetical order, say. Since there are $12$ months, there are $12^9$ possible sequences of birth months, and you’re intended to assume that they are equally likely. You need to find $N$, the number of sequences that meet the requirement that exactly two months appear in the sequence; the desired probability will then by $\frac{N}{12^9}$.

You cannot assume that $8$ people were born in one month and $1$ in another: it’s quite possible, for instance, that $3$ were born in one month and $6$ in another. I’ll get you started on one possible approach to counting these sequences.

Let $m_1$ be the birth month of the first person in line. There has to be exactly one other birth month represented in this group; Call it $m_2$. Let $S$ be the set of people among the remaining $8$ who were born in $m_1$; $S$ cannot be the entire set of $8$ people, since at least one of them has to have been born in $m_2$, but that’s the only restriction. Note that once we know $S$, $m_1$, and $m_2$, we know the entire sequence: the first person and everyone in $S$ were born in $m_1$, and every one of the $8$ who is **not** in $S$ was born in $m_2$.

- How many ways are there to choose $m_1$?
- How many ways are there to choose $m_2$?
- How many ways are there to choose $S$?
- Finally, how should you combine the answers to the first three questions in order to get $N$?

Comment: there should be 12 ways=(12 choose 1) to choose m1 since there are still 12 months to choose from.

there should be 11 ways=(11 choose 1) to choose m2 since there are now 11 months to choose from.

If S is the set of the remaining people from m1 then there should be 12*(9 choose 7) ways to choose? Since there are 8 remaining people - 1 from m2 so that would leave 7 people to choose from out of 9 times the 12 ways to choose the birth month? 

We can get N by doing m1*m2*S? So (12 choose 1)(11 choose 1)(9 choose 7)12

Am i even remotely close? I'm not really seeing the big picture here..

Comment: @user2644819: You’re right about the number of ways to choose $m_1$ and $m_2$, and you’re right about multiplying everything together, but you’re wrong about the number of ways to choose $S$. Let $R$ be the set of $8$ people after the first in line; $S$ is any subset of $R$ except $R$ itself. How many subsets does $R$ have? Now throw away the subset $R$.

Comment: if R is a subset does that mean permutation? 8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1?

Comment: @user2644819: No, just a subset. How many subsets does a set of $n$ elements have?

Comment: does a subset include all of the variations?
for example 1, 2, 3
we can have a subset of:1 or 2 or 3 or 1, 2 or 2, 1 <---same? or 1, 2, 3 or 1, 3, 2 <---same? or 2, 3, 1 <--again or 3, 1, 2 or 2, 1, 3

Comment: @user2644819: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are by definition the same **set**: the elements of a set are not considered to have any order. If order is to be taken into account, we’re talking about sequences or tuples, not about subsets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11229/discussion-between-user2644819-and-brian-m-scott)